# remove global variables in rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have defined some global variables in my server.r code using <<- operator.
Now I want those variables to be removed every time the user starts the application again, so I tried using rm, remove commands to delete these variables.
However I get the message object 'variable_name' not found, even though I can see that variable in global environment window of R. Screenshot attached.

Any idea how I should go about this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shiny does not use the variables you see in the global environment. Instead, it creates and manipulates objects for a particular session. That is the reason your code is unable to find the variables.

Refer the below link for more ideas on dealing with Pre-Session objects in shiny.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add global variable have a list initialize empty variables like this

```
values<- reactiveValues(attr_data<-NULL,attr_only_data<-NULL,descdata_temp<-NULL,gb_data<-NULL....)
```

If you wish to set the value while initializing, try something like this

```
values<- reactiveValues(attr_data<-mtcars, attr_only_data<-c(1,2,4,5), descdata_temp<-NULL, gb_data<-mtcars....)
```

Now if you want to update any variable you can do it by using the format

```
values$attr_data<-read.csv('....')
```

If you wish to access any variable you can use

```
values$attr_data
```

Hope this solves future queries as well